# Using $.get() to send data to servlet and insert into mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, jquery, servlets

Recently I use `$.getJSON` to send request to **flickr api** to get some photo info (I got 100 data totally)
and in `$.getJSON()`'s callback function, I use *`$.each()`* and **`$.get('myServlet.do')`** to send data to servlet then insert into MySQL database.

I think it should be no problems, but I found that my database would have duplicated data if I use the method above, does anyone know what is the problem?

the data is duplicated when servlet received, btw.

it would be very appreciated if someone can give me some advice...

this is my code that how I using *`$.get()`* :

```
$.getJSON('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select id,title,location.latitude,location.longitude,dates.taken,farm,server,secret from flickr.photos.info where photo_id in' + '(select id from flickr.photos.search(0) where text=\"' + queryText + '\" and has_geo=1 and lat=22.993299484253 and lon=120.20359802246 and content_type=1 and radius=20 and api_key=\"' + appid + '\" limit 100 ) and api_key=\"' + appid + '\"&format=json',

function (data) {
  var clientTime = $('#clientTime').html();
  $.each(data.query.results.photo,

  function () {
    console.log(this.id + " " + this.title + " " + this.farm + " " + this.server + " " + this.dates.taken);
    $.post('insertphotoinfo.do', {
      id: encodeURI(this.id),
      title: encodeURI(this.title),
      farm: encodeURI(this.farm),
      server: encodeURI(this.server),
      secret: encodeURI(this.secret),
      takendate: encodeURI(this.dates.taken),
      latitude: encodeURI(this.location.latitude),
      longitude: encodeURI(this.location.longitude),
      clientTime: encodeURI(clientTime)
    },

    function (Result) {

    });
  });
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing an example of the `GET` and seeing your servlet code. In general, though, you shouldn't use `GET` to do anything that changes server state; `GET` requests are meant to be *idempotent*. Use `POST` for anything that changes the state of the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I know nothing about servlets, but I can address this from a MySQL perspective.

At a very simple level, if you are picking up the same data from Flickr each time, and then inserting all that data into a database, you will end up with duplicate data.

An `INSERT` command, however it is wrapped up, adds a row of data. It does not check to see if that data already exists.

In abstract, there are three solutions to your problem.

1) Write something that checks if an item already exists and then run `UPDATE` or `INSERT` as appropriate.

2) If you always collect a full set of data, and you have nothing that is dependent on an ID column, you could remove all the existing data before you insert the new data. If it is the only data in the table, you can use `TRUNCATE`.

3) Mark an appropriate column in MySQL as being `UNIQUE`. This will prevent another row being added with the same data - but your servlet may not like being passed an error.

The simplest is solution 2.

You will have to figure out yourself how any of these solutions is achieved with servlets, but armed with the right concepts you should be able to find something.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but I might not describe the problem I met clearly, the log in $.each()'s callback function shows that data is not duplicated, but somehow the data servlet get is duplicated...
so, it's not about how should I do for mysql.

Comment: Ah. I'm assuming that if you have 100 rows in your database, then run your thing you end up with 200 rows. Then 300, 400 etc.

Are you saying that even if you have an empty database, then run `$.get('myServlet.do')` that you get everything multiple times? Is it exactly double every time?

How/where do you see that the data is duplicated?

Comment: I have an empty database, then run $.get('myServlet.do') and the data in database is "not everything" duplicated, some data multiple times, some data don't.
so I guess it has something wrong with callback function and servlet...